# HTML audio tag not working in localhost with apache tomcat

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, tomcat, audio

So I am building a web app with Java, apache tomcat, Spring MVC, HTML... And I am trying to play mp3 file that is on external hard drive on my server machine.
Code in html goes something like this:

```
<audio controls="">
    <source src="path/to/mp3/file" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and when I go to my internet and start this app in localhost I get this error in console:

> HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource
>   http://localhost:8080/path/to/mp3/file
>   failed.

I am pretty sure this means I don't have anything on that link, but how do I play audio file that is not in the same folder as HTML file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've simplified your question too much: I'm assuming that `path/to/mp3/file` refers to a URL that *should* start with `file:///`, and is not a `http://` URL - thus Tomcat doesn't deliver it, instead, the browser most likely interprets it as a relative URL on your server (localhost). That's where the 404 comes from, because it's elsewhere.

No Webserver (not even localhost) can reference anything on your local computer via access to the filesystem. Serve your audio through tomcat (with a http URL) and you can play it.

Comment: I am begginer with spring MVC and whole webserver thing, thing I am trying to achieve is something like webpage that will store all my audio and video files and i will put that app on raspberry pie that has only in my case 8Gb of memory, so I need to store all my video and audio files on external hard drive

Comment: Then check for tutorials on how to provide files external to your webapp for download in Tomcat. You simply can't access them through the `file` protocol, it will need to be `http`

Comment: So if I understood you right I need to create mapping for each audio/video file, and set that URL as source to audio tag?

Comment: Not individually, not file by file. You can do so by directory or any means possible. I mean it: Check tutorials on downloading. Comments on an answer are not the place to open yet another question. Downloading files in Java/Tomcat has been covered in numerous tutorials, and I've seen many questions on stackoverflow with this topic being closed as duplicates. There's _plenty_ of information on this topic available.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to post this as an answer I would be happy to mark it as the right answer!

Comment: not sure what you mean, as you're writing this in a comment to my answer